# Not all code paths return a value with code in a get{} statement

Tags: c#

I have a class, and I have this code to access some attributes, but the get statement says that not all code paths return a value:

```
public object this[int index, bool? type]       //Null = bool @ index, True 
= double @ index, False = full val
    {
        get
        {
            switch (type)  ///three way bool (ternoolean?)
            {
                case null:
                    return new returnDuo(_arr[index].tof, typeof(bool));
                case true:
                    return new returnDuo(_arr[index].val, typeof(decimal));
                case false:
                    return new returnDuo(getNum(), typeof(decimal));
            }
        }
        set
        {
            //Set
        }
    }
```

`returnDuo` is just a class that contains an object value, and a Type type that tells me what kind of value the object is.

Edit: The compiler should be able to tell that the variable can be in either of 3 states, they are the only 3 states the `bool?` object can hold.

Edit 2: Nvm, thanks

Comment: Compiler is not smart enough to know that type can only be null, true or false. you need to add a default case. btw why do you depend on a nullable bool to determine a type, that seems like a bad design.

Comment: I do, because there isnt a variable that is only able to contain 3 states.

Comment: Would if(true)/if(false)/else /*null*/ statements work?

Comment: yes it would work

Comment: If you want a type that can be one of 3 states then go make one! Define a enum and use that to represent the variable.